# WatchOS2 Context Menu not working with BecomeCurrentPage

Tags: watchos-2

I setup a watchOS 2 context menu in the storyboard and it works fine UNITL I use the same page with `becomeCurrentPage`:

```
override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
    super.awakeWithContext(context)
    setTitle("Activated")
    self.becomeCurrentPage()
}
```

If I go to another page, then return, the context menu then works with force touch. Any suggestions?

Comment: Would be nice to have minimum code to reproduce the bug, cause that works fine for me.
could it be that you miss some inits? //try step by step debuging

Comment: Why are you calling becomeCurrentPage()?.. context menu don't need it.

Comment: I wanted to use a page view controller and have the second page in the list as the first page. This problem is intermittent and seems to have disappeared and I can't recreate it. It almost seemed like an installation issue, but I don't have evidence to support that.  For now its gone and I'll probably get back to it only if it reappears.